# New iTerm2 windows have the wrong colors

Tags: terminal, iterm, color

My current iTerm2 window (which I've likely been reusing for months/years) has the color theme set just the way I like it. However when I open a new window or tab the colors are all a bit off (but new panes are fine). This means that if I ever close my main window, I'll lose these colors.

How can I fix it so that all windows/tabs use the colors from this one window? For example, maybe it's possible for me to create a theme based on this window's current colors?

[image: screenshot of the two windows]

Comment: You use Windows, tabs and pane in your question - there are only two of these - window and tab. Can you update what you mean

Comment: I'm using iTerm's terminology. Windows contain tabs, and tabs can be split into panes. https://imgur.com/a/DWkvdry

Comment: What profiles are you using and in them what fonts and colours?

Comment: I'm using the default profile. The color presets seem to apply only to new windows, and none of them match the colors from my old window. https://imgur.com/a/vIFW7ID So I'm looking for a way to "extract" the colors from the old window.

Comment: Followup: I ended up manually copying the colors using the dropper tool in the Colors section of the profile settings. https://imgur.com/7o0qTgh